# Obter valores Checkbox criados dinamicamente

Tags: html, python, flask

Desenvolvendo uma aplicação python utilizando o framework Flask para realizar um cadastro simple

Estou com o seguinte problema, eu tenho um cadastro de licitações e essas licitações podem ter várias categorias, as categorias são cadastradas pelo usuário e aparecem na tela de cadastro da licitação em forma de checkbox para o mesmo ir selecionando as devidas categorias

Até a parte listar todos os checkbox na tela da licitação, foi tranquilo e está funcionando, porém agora eu não sei qual é a maneira mais correta de se obter os ids das solicitações listadas. Existe uma forma simples de percorrer todo um grupo de checkboxes, afinal não sei o id deles por que são criados de acordo com oq está salvo no banco.

A solução que pensei, foi buscar todos os ids de categoria no banco e ir buscando de acordo com o padrão que cirei para o nome, mas isso não me parece a forma mais correta.

Para exemplificar melhor o problema, segue o código reduzido da minha página html e das minhas funções no controller

Página html

```
<form action="{{url_for('gravar_licitacao')}}" method="POST" role="form">
  <label>Categorias:</label>
  {% for categoria in categorias %}
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbCat{{ categoria._id }}" value="{{ categoria._id }}">{{categoria.nome}}       
  {% endfor %}
  <hr>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-default"/>
</form>
```

Controller

```
@app.route("/cadastro_licitacao")
def cadastro_licitacao():
    categorias = Categoria.query.all()
    return render_template("licitacao/cadastro_licitacao.html", categorias = categorias)

@app.route("/gravar_licitacao", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def gravar_licitacao():
    if request.method == "POST":        
        #QUAL È A MANEIRA CORRETA PARA EU OBTER UMA LISTA COM AS CATEGORIAS AQUI

    return redirect(url_for("lista_licitacoes"))
```

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859903/get-the-value-of-a-checkbox-in-flask
espero que tenha ajudado !

Answer (score 0):

pode obter os dados do formulário assim:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    valor = request.form["id"]
```

Comment: O problema é que mão sei o id dos checkboxes para passar para o método. Eles são criados dinamicamente e esse é o meu problema